# how to calculate percentage from a vector of counts

Tags: r, percentage

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
> dat <- data.frame(Operation = c("Login", "Posted", "Deleted"), `Total Count` = c(5, 25, 40), check.names = FALSE)
> dat
  Operation Total Count
1     Login           5
2    Posted          25
3   Deleted          40
```

I want to calculate the percentage for each Operation, e.g., what percentage of Operations were `Login`.  I'd expect a result like:

```
  Operation Total Count Percentage
1     Login           5 0.07142857
2    Posted          25 0.35714286
3   Deleted          40 0.57142857
```

Since the counts are already summarized, `table()` doesn't work:

```
> table(dat$`Total Count`)

 5 25 40 
 1  1  1
```

Comment: I edited this question to improve it - it's a useful, albeit basic, question that gets a lot of views and ranks high in Google results.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call your column `Total.Count` instead of `Total Count`; spaces in names don't work well.

If you have your data in a data frame called, say, `my.df`:

```
my.df$Pct <- my.df$Total.Count / sum(my.df$Total.Count)
my.df
##   Operation Total.Count        Pct
## 1     Login           5 0.07142857
## 2    Posted          25 0.35714286
## 3   Deleted          40 0.57142857
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use function `prop.table()` to calculate percentages (assuming that column name is `TotalCount`).

```
df$percent<- prop.table(df$TotalCount)

df
  Operation TotalCount    percent
1     Login          5 0.07142857
2    Posted         25 0.35714286
3   Deleted         40 0.57142857
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `dplyr` :

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(Percent = TotalCount / sum(TotalCount))
```

Note that I changed the column name to `TotalCount` with no spaces.